# Android Twitter fabric library error

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I have integrated twitter fabric sdk in android project. It has 5 libraries imported in workspace with project. It was working fine. I have removed the project from workspace and import it again, now all libraries showing error and after run Clean+build project command it is not solving.
error message:

> The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved   MicroSoftTechEd     Unknown Java Problem
>       The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\Microsoftteched_data\MicroSoftTechEd\kit-libs\io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric\bin\io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric.jar'   com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core        Build path  Build Path Problem
>       The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\Microsoftteched_data\MicroSoftTechEd\kit-libs\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core\bin\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core.jar'   com-twitter-sdk-android_tweet-ui        Build path  Build Path Problem
>       The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\Microsoftteched_data\MicroSoftTechEd\kit-libs\io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric\bin\io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric.jar'   com-twitter-sdk-android_tweet-composer      Build path  Build Path Problem
>       The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\Microsoftteched_data\MicroSoftTechEd\kit-libs\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter\bin\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter.jar' MicroSoftTechEd     Build path  Build Path Problem
>       The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    com-digits-sdk-android_digits       Unknown Java Problem
>       The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\Microsoftteched_data\MicroSoftTechEd\kit-libs\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core\bin\com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter-core.jar'   com-digits-sdk-android_digits       Build path  Build Path Problem
>       The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\Microsoftteched_data\MicroSoftTechEd\kit-libs\com-digits-sdk-android_digits\bin\com-digits-sdk-android_digits.jar' com-twitter-sdk-android_twitter     Build path  Build Path Problem

solution required. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What you using 'Eclipse' or Android studio ..?

Comment: If you imported project again, you need to set dependencies again for the project